# How to pass form-data and json in same API in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, xamarin

I have an API method in Xamarin that uses .NET Core as a back end and I want to use it to transfer both form-data and JSON format.I have read some examples and I tried to figure a method to make it work.Currently I have this:

```
 public async Task AddUser(User user, MediaFile file)
    {
        string userRegisterUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:53547/api/PostUser";
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        formData.Add(new StreamContent(file.GetStream()),"file",string.Format("{0}.png",Guid.NewGuid()));
                formData.Add(new StringContent(json),"user");
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
                {
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(userRegisterUrl, formData);
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                       
                    }
                }
    }
```

The problem is that no matter what I do I keep getting this error:"415 Unsupported Media Type".Now I know that what it's trying to say by this is that the server will not accept the payload format as it's unsupported but I have no idea how to do it in such way that it will not require me to install external nuget packages to achieve it.I know it is possible and what I have tried is the following:

1. First I have tried to create an HttpContent that will get the media file as stream and I added some headers to it with ContentDispositionHeaderValue of "form-data" and a MediaTypeHeaderValue of "application/octet-stream".The json format I would serialize it as I did in my method and pass it to the MultipartFormDataContent value but without any success as I got the error mentioned above.
2. The second try I didn't pass any headers to the media file,the json object remained unchanged and I used a try catch block to pass the content but without any luck as it gave me the same error.

The method above is the final method that I have implemented and this is what I have on the server-side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user,IFormFile file)
    {
      

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_env.WebRootPath))
        {
            _env.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
        }
        if(user!=null)
        { 
        _context.User.Add(user);
            var users = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "uploads", user.Name);
            if (!Directory.Exists(users)) Directory.CreateDirectory(users);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(users, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.IdUser }, user);
     
    }
```

Initially I had both methods separated,one for uploading the image and the other for storing user data but I want to create a folder with the user's name every time a new user is registered and someone suggested I should merge the two of them.How can I achieve the desired result without having to deal with the unsupported format?

Comment: What i do, is still separate async methods, the one that uploads gets upload id, then i can use this id to attach the upload to user in a separate method (ex: AttachAvatar = id when updating user). That way every 24h you can clear all 24h-old unassigned uploads from server.

Comment: @NickKovalsky Thank you for your response!Can I have an example by any chance of how it should work? :)

Comment: if my net.core api i'm receiving as " public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(                IFormCollection form, List<IFormFile> files)"

Comment: to post i have  MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                ByteArrayContent file = new ByteArrayContent(ReadFully(stream));
                form.Add(file, "files", filename);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assignTo))
                    form.Add(new StringContent(assignTo), "assignTo");
...
response = await myClient.PostAsync(uri, form);

Answer (score 0):

Alternatif solution you can use [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#multipart-uploads) to simplify your request. It can be used in any xamarin forms project with/withour `ReactiveUI`

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have already tried with Refit and I still get the same error.